# Get the value from the database, using the property in the user control

Tags: c#, entity-framework, user-controls

I am designing a user control that has inside this user control (label, text box and check box list), I defined a property for this user control that when we enter a value inside it, a value from the database for We returned
Apparently, there is no problem with the code I wrote, but I don't actually receive an answer.
I wanted to get your help to solve this problem.
I will send you the code I wrote in the properties RegionID.
Thank you for your cooperation

```
private int _regionID = 0; 
public int RegionID
    {
        get
        {
            return _regionID;
        }
        set
        {
            _regionID = value;

            if (value < 1 && value> 4)
            {
                _regionID = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Models.DataBaseContext dataBaseContext = null;

                try
                {
                    dataBaseContext =
                        new Models.DataBaseContext();

                    Models.Region region
                        = dataBaseContext.Regions
                        .Where(current => current.Region_Id == value)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    captionLabelControl.Text = region.Region_Name;
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {

                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the database contain values?  Is your connection string correct?  When you start application the DbContext should be filled from the database.  Most likely this is not happening.

Comment: Yes, my database has the initial values, but I can't understand why this problem exists.

Comment: What database are you using?  If it is SQL Server you can check the log files using SSMS to see if you application is making a connection.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to put much logic in properties, especially database logic.  Also this property now has side effects on other properties.  The database call should be moved out of this setter and into a business logic class that's fired off when the user submits the changes (either by clicking out of the input field or by clicking a submit button).  You need to implement a model for the user control that is the source of these properties and implements the INotifyChanged interface (or similar).  Try to make these properties as simple as possible and push the logic elsewhere.